# how to check calling function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a common error function which is called from many places. I want to know from which function this was called. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: There used to be something called `arguments.callee` - which you can maybe try.. No guarantees but.

Comment: No, there isn't, not reliably. You can inspect the callstack by putting a `debugger` statement in your error handling method though.

Comment: you can debug with break-point in the function using firebug and then looking stack

Answer (score 0):

In any javascript function you can use

```
 arguments.callee.caller
```

Comment: Just works with javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

if You want to execute JS in chrome you have to do like this

go to console and type your JS and enter!